# i need return many ids from relationship in model

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-api

need return many ids from relationship in model

I need help fetching the data for these ids from another table. Now it saves the multiple ids, but when querying, the response appears only individually. Please, I want to show all returns of ids

my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\BookingRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\BookingResource;
use App\Models\Booking;
use App\Models\Installment;


class BookingController extends Controller
{
    
    public function store(Request $request, Booking $booking)
    {

        $booking = Booking::create($request->only([
            'patient_id',
            'setting_id',
            'procedure_id',
            'procedure_ids',
            
        ]));
    
        return new BookingResource($booking);
    }
 }
```

my Model

In the model I added the relationship between the columns and the fetch works perfectly, but for one result I want to return with all the results

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Booking extends Model
{
    use \EloquentFilter\Filterable;

    protected $table = 'bookings';

    protected $keyType = 'integer';
    protected $casts = [
        'procedure_ids' => 'array',
    ];


    protected $fillable = ['setting_id', 'procedure_id','procedure_ids'];

    public function patient()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Patient');
    }

   
    public function procedure()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Setting', 'procedure_id');
    }

    public function procedures()
    {
        return  $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Setting', 'procedure_ids');
    }

  
    public function setting()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Setting');
    }

   
    public function installments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Installment');
    }
}
```

my Request

Added in the request * with the last parameter to receive multiple ids

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class BookingRequest extends FormRequest
{
  
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // check if update request or store request
        $id =  $this->booking->id ?? "NULL";

        return [
         'procedure_ids.*' => ['required_if:type,==,procedure', 'array', 'exists:settings,id'],     
        ];
    }


}
```

i need my results to be

```
{
    "data": {
        "patient_id": "3",
        "setting_id": "572",
        "procedure_id": "580",
        "procedure_ids": [
            "680",
            "679",
            "678"
        ],
        "date": "2021-06-08",
        "time": "20:59",
        "total": "500",
        "unpaid": "0",
        "id": 123,
        "procedures": [
         "680" {
            "id": 680,
            "type": "procedure_typs",
            "title": "Surgery"
        },
         "681" {
            "id": 681,
            "type": "procedure_typs",
            "title": "codo"
    }]
}
```

not

``````
"data": {
        "patient_id": "3",
        "setting_id": "572",
        "procedure_id": "580",
        "procedure_ids": [
            "680",
            "679",
            "678"
        ],
        "date": "2021-06-08",
        "time": "20:59",
        "total": "500",
        "unpaid": "0",
        "id": 123,
     "procedures": {
            "id": 680,
            "type": "procedure_typs",
            "title": "Surgery",
           }
`````
``````

Comment: The `procedure_ids` looks a lot like a Many-to-Many relationship (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). I think it would be much easier to use this relationship and add a method on the model that maps the entities to an array of id's if you really need that.

Comment: use Many_to_Many relationship between books table and procedures table (search for it "pivot table" )